# Eq and PartialEq matching two unmatching types being equal

Tags: rust

I was trying to implement `PartialEq`, for two different types, in a way that one member of enum `A` is equal to one member of enum `B`.

```
impl PartialEq for A {
    fn eq(&self, other: &B) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

but, I got error:

```
change the parameter type to match the trait: `&EventType`
```

How can I get this done? is it even possible to overload like python `__eq__` to match any two random types?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, and the full error from `cargo check` (not your IDE).

Comment: `PartialEq` should be `PartialEq<B>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement comparision to another `Rhs` but you have to explicitly provide that type parameter:

```rust
impl PartialEq<B> for A {
    fn eq(&self, other: &B) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            //…
        }
    }
}
```

Or else it's using the default of `Self` from [it's definiton](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html):

> ```rust
> pub trait PartialEq<Rhs = Self>
> // …
> ```